# Accidentally deleted authorized_keys on vagrant box

Tags: linux, ssh, vagrant

I accidentally deleted my `authorized_keys` file on my vagrant box and I can't SSH into it anymore but I still have a console connected to it.

How do I go about re-making this folder so it allows me to connect again?

I have my `.d.vagrant/insecure_private_key` on my host machine, do I need to create a public key of that and move that over or do i need to move the private key over too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run `vagrant ssh-config` to review which private key the VM is using

If you're using the vagrant insecure key, you can

1. create the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` with 600 mode
2. download the [vagrant public key](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/keys/vagrant.pub) into this file

If you have used your own private key, repeat the steps but create the public key from your key.

You dont need to move the private key, it must stay local and is only needed for you to login into the VM (unless you ssh from the VM into other servers like github or other ssh which will need the key, but thats another thing)

Answer (score 6):

Run the following commands on the host:

```
cd <vagrant_project_directory>
ssh-keygen -y -f `vagrant ssh-config | grep IdentityFile | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev`
```

It will display a public key for the currently configured private key.

Add the result to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the Vagrant box machine.

Comment: I've added the public key back in but vagrant keeps asking for a password, am I missing something?

Comment: I see. I don't have a .vagrant folder though, I have a .vagrant.d folder, are they the same thing? (I assume not because my .vagrant.d folder structure doesn't match the one in your post..)

Comment: Ah I see. I've found my .vagrant folder but there's no private key file in there, does that mean it's using the default still?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I appreciate it, but it's fixed now. The command above didn't run correctly (I think it's because my host is a windows machine) but I used the tips in the other comments to fix it. The issue was that when I recreated authorized_keys I thought it was supposed to be a folder and didn't realize it's an actual file

Comment: learn something with the `ssh-keygen` command alias, never though about it but makes full sense.